# TFS 2015.1 alerts for Pull Request not showing on multiple source control collection

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-alerts

I have a server with TFS2015.1 installed and since this update I have added some git repositories to an existing collection.

Historically it was using TFS version control, but more recently we have started to look at using git more prolifically, and because of this I believe the alerts available do not include a pull request option.

Is there something I can ask our ALM team to try.

I am hunting for a template change if possible, is this something that an update x of TFS might allow.

I have to consider the possible of needing separate collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with TFS 2015 Update 1. It has been fixed in TFS 2015 update 2. There is no solution to fix this on Update 1 other than upgrading the TFS instance.

Comment: I was looking if that would be the case, so thanks for confirming. We should be upgrading in a month or so.

Comment: i am having similar problem, the difference is that i am using TFS Update 2 and most of my projects that are using Git as secondary repo has the pull request alert. Only one project so far does not have the pull request alert. Suggestions appreciated..

Comment: Try detaching and attaching the project collection. If that doesn't work, You'll probably need to contact support.

Comment: how will it help, you think?

Comment: It forces some of the internal consistency checks on the upgrade scripts etc.